# Difference between u"string" and ur"string" in Python

Tags: python, types

From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> The solution is to use Python’s raw string notation for regular
>   expression patterns; backslashes are not handled in any special way in
>   a string literal prefixed with 'r'. So r"\n" is a two-character string
>   containing '\' and 'n', while "\n" is a one-character string
>   containing a newline. Usually patterns will be expressed in Python
>   code using this raw string notation.

Types also match; `type(u"text") == type(ur"text")`, and same goes when you remove `u`. Therefore, I have to ask: what is the difference between these two? If there is no difference, why use `r` at all?

Comment: Are you using Python 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example:

```
>>> len(ur"tex\t")
5
>>> len(u"tex\t")
4
```

Without `r`, the `\t` is *one* character (the tab) so the string has length 4.

Use `r` if you want to build a regular expression that involves `\`. In an non-`r` string, you'd have to escape these which is not funny.

```
>>> len(u"\\")
1
>>> len(ur"\\")
2
```

Comment: To add to this: 'r' changes how the Python parser interprets the string, i.e. handling escape sequences. It does not result in a different type as with 'u' or 'b'.